# In Neo4J how do I get the largest node id in the graph?

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, cypher

I'm running a script that iterates through all the nodes.  Initially, I thought the maximum node id would correspond to the total number of nodes in the graph which I retrieved by this Cypher query over REST:

```
START n=node(*) RETURN count(n)
```

However, as I iterate through each number, I see that some nodes at certain ids just don't exist.  So, this means my maximum id node is a number larger than the total number of nodes.  Any idea how I can retrieve this number?  I strongly prefer Cypher or Rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this number through JMX, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.4.2/operations-monitoring.html or with Java via

```
Neo4jManager manager = new Neo4jManager( graphDb.getManagementBean( Kernel.class ) );
long nodeIDsInUse    = manager.getPrimitivesBean.getNumberOfNodeIdsInUse();
```

This is also exposed to the Webadmin JMX endpoint via REST starting at

```
http://localhost:7474/db/manage/server/jmx/domain/org.neo4j/instance%3Dkernel%230%2Cname%3DPrimitive%20count?_=1342719685294
```

Comment: Among other things, I got this back:
`"attributes" : [ {
==>     "description" : "An estimation of the number of nodes used in this Neo4j instance",
==>     "name" : "NumberOfNodeIdsInUse",
==>     "value" : 12345,
==>     "isReadable" : "true",
==>     "type" : "long",
==>     "isWriteable" : "false ",
==>     "isIs" : "false "
==>   },`

Unless I'm missing something, this still looks like the total number of nodes.

Comment: `NumberOfNodeIdsInUse` is not giving you the actual number of nodes, but the number of IDs given out. Isn't that what you want? In HA scenarios, the IDs are chunked between slaves, so you would have a count in steps of 1000s per default.

Comment: So, just to be clear, if 5 ids are given out does that mean that 0,1,2,3,4 were given out?  Or, for whatever reason, can ids ever be skipped so 0,1,3,5,10 be given out?  In either case, `NumberOfNodeIdsInUse` would be 5.

Comment: mmh, it is saying the Number of IDs in use, which means if it is 5, then 0,1,2,3,4 are in use. In clustered environments, chunks of 1000 IDs are given out to clusters, so not all of these are actually used, but reserved.

Comment: The interface `org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService` does have a `getManagementBean()` method.