# Short incremental uinque id for neo4j

Tags: django, python-3.x, neo4j, cypher

I use django with neo4j as database. I need to use short url based on node ids in my rest api. In neo4j there is an id used in database that [didn't recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754622/8258902) to use in app, and there is approach to use uuid that is too long for my short urls. So I add my uid generator:

```
def uid_generator():
    last_id = db.cypher_query("MATCH (n) RETURN count(*) AS lastId")[0][0][0]
    if last_id is None:
        last_id = 0
    last_id = str(last_id)
    hash = sha256()
    hash.update(str(time.time()).encode())
    return hash.hexdigest()[0:(max(2, len(last_id)))] + str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '')[0:(max(2, len(last_id)))]
```

I have two question, First I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8160181/8258902) in stack overflow and still not sure that `MATCH (n) RETURN count(*) AS lastId` is `O(1)` there was no reference to that! Is there any reference for that answer? Second is there a better approach to do in both id uniqueness and speed?

Comment: You can check yourself by profiling the query: `profile MATCH (n) RETURN count(*)` You should see `NodeCountFromCountStore`, meaning it's a O(1) lookup from the counts store rather than counting it in the graph itself.

Comment: If you ever plan to delete nodes in the graph, that would throw a wrench in this approach.

Comment: @InverseFalcon thanks for your answer, now what is the best approach for short unique id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should put a unique constraint on the id property to make sure there are no collisions created by parallel create statements. This requires using a label, but you NEED this fail-safe if you plan to do anything serious with this data. But this way, you can have rolling ids for different labels. (All indexed labels will have a count table. UNIQUE CONSTRAINT also creates an index)

Second, you should do the generation and creation in the same cypher like this

```
MATCH (n:Node) WITH count(*) AS lastId
CREATE (:Node{id:lastId})
```

This will minimize time between generation and commit, reducing chances of collision. (Remember to retry on failed attempts from unique violations)

I'm not sure what you are doing with the hash, just that you are doing it wrong. Either you generate a new time based UUID (It will require no parameters) and use it as is, or you use the incriminating id. (By altering a UUID, you invalidate the logic that guaranteed uniqueness, thus significantly increasing collision chance)

You can also store the current index count in a node like is explained [here](https://gist.github.com/jacquibo/8012859). It's not guaranteed to be thread safe, but shouldn't be a problem as long as you have Unique Constraints in place, and retry on constraint violations. This will be more tolerant of deleting nodes.

Comment: In last line I use combination of epoch time sha256 hash and uuid.uuid4 to improve my uid uniqueness. I use count of nodes to determine length of uid that created,because I need my uid be incremental.

Comment: @SaeedBabashahi UUID's are not magic. They are logical algorithms designed to minimize collision even when generated on different systems. By altering it, you can only make it less unique (unless you are only concatenating). You need to use either a UUID, or an incrementing ID. I will give you a compromise though. Use `YYYYMMDDhhmmss-<UUID>` for your index. Or in words, use a formatted date from largest to smallest unit for the order part, and append a UUID to the end to insure uniqueness.

Comment: An argument can be made that what you really want is a "Creation Date" field. As indexes don't care about the order items where created. So the real question is why do you need a unique and increasing primary id? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Like I said in question, I need short incremental ids to handle short url to nodes in rest api.

Comment: @SaeedBabashahi Incremental does not help (or hurt) short URLs in any way (unless you are using a pure numeric incrementing id). If Tiny URLs is all you want, than use a tiny url service like Googles [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/). Or use a proxy server with URL rewriting. So you still need to answer why the incremental part is important to the answer. (Otherwise, a tiny url service can do the same job without compromising data integrity) The Why is more important than the What.

Comment: By incremental I didn't mean 1,2,3,... I need short uid start with length 4 and uid length growth with count of nodes to prevent collision

Comment: @SaeedBabashahi That would be "expanding id". "Increment" means "cause a discrete increase", AKA, each ID must be larger than the previous. Either way, this is why auto-increment IDs are still used. Neo4j doesn't support this automicly, but you can get [close](https://gist.github.com/jacquibo/8012859). As long as you have Unique constraints and retries in place. You can even convert the number to a hex representation to compress it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not good because it's based on the number of node in the database.

What happened if you  create a node (call it A), and then delete a random node, and then create a new node (call it B).

A and B will have the same ID, and I think that's why you have added a hash in code based on the time (but I barely understand the line :)).

On the other side, Neo4j's ID ensure you to have a unique ID across the database, but not in the time. Per default, Neo4j recycle unused ID (an ID is release when a node is deleted).

You can change this behavour by changing the configuration (see the  doc [HERE](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.ids.reuse.types.override) ) : `dbms.ids.reuse.types.override=RELATIONSHIP`

Becarefull with such a configuration, the size of your database on your harddrive can only increase, even if you delete nodes.

Comment: quick clarification. If you create nodes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and delete 3, the next node generated will receive id 3. (as apposed to having 2 nodes with id 5 simultaneously as your wording suggests) Node id's are guaranteed to be unique, and won't change during the life of a node. (It's when you have to delete a node that using this ID can cause inconsistencies)

Comment: In last line I use combination of epoch time sha256 hash and uuid.uuid4 to improve my uid uniqueness. I use count of nodes to determine length of uid that created,because I need my uid be incremental.

Answer (score -1):

Why not create your own identifier? You can get the maximum of your last identifier (let's call it RN for record number).

> match (n) return max(n.RN) as lastID

max is one of several numeric functions in cypher.

Comment: this solution is not good, due to its complexity. Its execution time directly depends on the number of nodes in the DB.

Comment: The question is about how can I have my own identifier!!